# Set a breakpoint for a win command without an address

Tags: x64dbg

How to make these columns empty or make a new breakpoint where they are empty? I just need **a stop at these win commands** (in the summary column), not at a specific address.
[image]
I don't know what exactly should be in these columns and that is why I need them empty.

**So I need to set a breakpoint for a command without an address.** Maybe other debuggers can do this.

UPDATE:
**I am looking for this functionality in x64dbg:**
[image]
So there are no addresses. Does it support this?

Comment: The colum doesn't affect the breakpoint, it is just for visual purposes

Comment: But I see that they work for these addresses. I need for any addresses. I don't know how to correctly set a breakpoint for Win API functions (without setting an address).

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but you can do Ctrl+G -> type the name of winapi function -> Enter -> F2 to set breakpoint

Comment: It founds addresses and I should set breakpoints for all of them. I need to set one time only for a function. So x64dbg shouldn't check addresses.

Comment: If you do it like in my last comment the breakpoint will be called every time, no matter from which address your function was called. If you want to do it like in your screen (I don't see a reason, but ok) you can go to CPU window -> Right click -> Search for -> All modules -> Intermodular calls, type the function in the bottom input, right click -> Set breakpoint on all commands, but it will have pretty much the same effect as what I mentioned above.

Comment: If there are 4 results for GetDlgItemTextA?

Comment: Just right click and -> Set breakpoint on all commands. But as I said, you don't need to do that. Just do it like at my first comment and your breakpoint will be triggered at every function call, not matter from which address it was called.

Comment: I want to try 2 ways. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/IcRICPJ.png So I should set it 4 times? I see that "Disassembly" repeats.

Comment: Yes. You can ignore the disassembly, it means nothing, it is just for the visual purpose...

Comment: The latest x64dbg added them all after only 1 setting.

Comment: That is how it should work... It is called "Set breakpoint on ALL commands" for a reason

Comment: But it doesn't work. No breakpoint. I don't understand. Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/mwF3u8o.png

Comment: Because you didn't set the breakpoint at GetDlgItemTextA (to do this, do what I have said in first comment). You set in on every call to the function, but not in the function itself.

Comment: But what is the difference? Functions start executing after a call. So the call should be a bit earlier. It should come one after one, but the call isn't stopped.

Comment: Maybe it is not called directly, but via some pointer dereferencing, so the x64dbg won't see it while listing all intermodular calls. That's why option from my first comment is better.